# JFileChooser doesn't return full file name on OSX 10.7

Tags: java, macos, swing, jfilechooser

The problem is that the `File` object returned by `JFileChooser` has incomplete file name. To be more exact it returns the file name without the file extension part. I have tried retrieving the path using `getPath`, `getAbsolutePath` and `getCanonicalPath` but it still returns same path without the extension part. Same program and code work fine on Windows, Linux, and OSX 10.6

The issue occurs on OSX 10.7.4 with Java SE 10.6.0_33-b03-424. Does anyone know a work-around for this, or can at least confirm this happening?

Edit:

```
JFileChooser myImageChooser = new JFileChooser();
myImageChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
int val = myImageChooser.showDialog(NewJFrame.this, "Select Image");

        JFileChooser myImageChooser = new JFileChooser();
        myImageChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int val = myImageChooser.showDialog(NewJFrame.this,
                "Select Image");

        if (val == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = myImageChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
            System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());

            //loadImage(f);
            //Util.event("LoadImage", f.getName());
        }
```

Also I just noticed something very interesting, that it works correctly for some files, same files that have visible extension in Finder, but for those that Finder doesn't show extension this fails. I have checked that the files actually have extensions by doing `ls` in bash terminal.

Edit 2:

After turning on 'Show all filename extensions' in Finder JFileChooser started to return file names with extension. That looks like a design error in JFileChooser's underlying implementation. And that doesn't really help to solve the problem since in my case this is a consumer product targeted for average users.

Comment: I doubt there is such a severe issue in Apple JVM. Could you post a complete example that reproduces the issue? Silly question but, are you sure that the file you selected has an extension?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet please see my edit for semi-complete example, and yes, file extensions show in terminal (directory listing), but not in OSX's Finder program. That shouldn't be a problem IMO, windows doesn't show file extensions in explorer by default neither.

Comment: I wonder what happens if you have two files with same name and different (invisible) extension. Are the two files considered to be the same?

Comment: I know this is going to sound dumb, but, can you verify that the file you're selecting has an extension (go to the terminal and have a look) and that the file really isn't a folder

Comment: @Guillaume Polet That works fine with the OS, and JFileChooser displays 2 files with same name and then returns same names(no extension) for both files.

Comment: Yes, but I wondered what happened if you use `File.equals` between those two files. My bet would be that it returns `false`. If it does, then there must be some way to disambiguate the 2 files and thus a way for you to find out that extension. If it does not, then there is a severe issue in Apple JVM.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet Kudos to you sir! To test your suggestion, I did setMultipleSelectionEnabled(true) and retrieved File[] with getSelectedFiles from JFileChooser bam-> Files in the array have full names with extensions. And  of course File.equals returned false. I have yet to try comparing files selected one after another with single file selection, but that's for some other day. Now I can get the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I update some parts in your code, and I get this output:

> C:\Users\Arno\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\RendererInfo.txt
>   C:\Users\Arno\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\RendererInfo.txt
>   RendererInfo.txt
>   C:\Users\Arno\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\RendererInfo.txt

Here is the updated code:

```
JFileChooser myImageChooser = new JFileChooser();
    myImageChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    int val = myImageChooser.showDialog(null, "Select Image");

    if (val == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File f = myImageChooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile()
                .getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile()
                    .getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
        System.err.println(myImageChooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());

        // loadImage(f);
        // Util.event("LoadImage", f.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your output is clearly from Windows os :) The problem happens only on Mac OSX

Comment: @Arno OP stated that it works on Windows. His issues seems to be directly linked to MacOSX 10.7 and Java6.

Comment: :), Yea, I use a windows pc, sorry, I will seek a bit more ;)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a feature of finder.

If I turn extension hiding off in Finder, I get the extensions, if I turn extension hiding on in Finder, I don't

Check out http://www.fileinfo.com/help/mac_show_extensions to see how to switch between the two

Comment: This is annoying, I could repeat your results, turned extension hiding off and on and off and now I always get the extentions